Trying to find out why pages refresh sometimes after the page has fully hydrated
We've recently launched a site built with Nuxt 3, CMS with Storyblok, hosted on Netlify with ISR render mode.
https://epc-improvements.co.uk/
We have noticed that pages occasionally refresh after full hydration. I suspect this is related to ISR, but I can't seem to track down why it is happening. Does anybody have any experience with similar issues or have any ideas how I can work out what is causing pages to refresh?
It's not brilliant from a UX perspective, but it's awful if a customer has started filling out a form and has to re-enter data again because the page refreshed on them.
Certain pages which can support it have been switched into pre-render mode. We think this has helped, but because the issue is not consistent, it is really hard to tell. We've also tried logging to console whether the page is stale or not, but we are struggling to fetch the current cache status from Nuxt 3.
Any thoughts or ideas would be much appreciated

Please read your question again: how anybody is supposed to guess that without a [repro]? Maybe you have something triggering the navigation, a middleware, or a 3rd party plugin? Try to put a Sentry or anything other kind of monitoring on a beforeunload window event to start narrowing where it might come from. Double-check possible hydration issues too. There is no such behavior as random reloading  out of the box. Maybe try to host it somewhere else to see if it's a platform issue? The rendering issue should not be the culprit but you need to narrow it down for sure, have bugs consistently.

Hi Kissu, thanks for your reply. I appreciate thats it's near impossible to determine a fix for my issue, that's why I was asking if anybody else had experienced issues similar to mine or had any idea how I might go tracking down the problem. I would love to have given an example of it not working but as it's quite random (or I at least do not yet know what triggers it), I've been unable to do so.
Thanks for your suggestion regarding beforeunload - I'll see if we can monitor that and work back from there.

For anybody who comes across this same issue, we did eventually identify the culprit. Our bundle included Vite PWA, which natively refreshes the page when it detects stale cache. Switching Vite from "Autorefresh" to "Notify" has fixed the issue.
